# Amplitude modulation using microcntroller

Tags: microcontroller, amplitude-modulation

I have found this circuit diagram for amplitude modulation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3I_e7gIyfQg).

[image]Only difference is, the output of modulated signal will be fed to a push-pull transformer.  The message signals to be modulated are standard waveforms which may come from microcontroller. Secondly I can create the carrier signal from a microcontroller as well.

I have a rough idea about the circuit as below:

[image]

All 3 signals can be created by a microcontroller.

Current to be supplied in probes is less than 100mA.

Carrier Frequency is 10KHz.

Signal Frequency is 1 to 150Hz.

My questions are:

1. Can I avoid some or all of the analog circuit shown above?
2. Is there any diffrence in the final modulated signal if created using pulse width modulation technique instead of amplitude modulation technique? PWM is provided in hardware in the microcontroller.

Comment: You might want to do some review of biomedical electronics safety before probing human bodies. Otherwise we may need to alert MIB.

Comment: I have already added  the isolation transformer .

Comment: None of those circuits result in amplitude modulation - they merely add the carrier to the audio signal. Modulation is a multiplication process.

Comment: @Kevin White I agree . But how to do it in microcontroller. please guide.

Comment: @Israr - depends what you mean by a microcontroller - modulation is a multiplication operation. To perform modulation in realtime internal to an MCU would mean being able to perform many millions of multiplications per second to produce carrier frequencies in the 1MHz region. As well as a way of outputting that data to an external DAC. That is not possible on small MCUs.

Comment: @Kevin White - My carrier frequency is 10KHz and Signal is 1-150Hz max..Signal is not from outside, it will be generated in MCU only.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this question. 1. I still don't understand what you are trying to do. If you want to do AM wi a uC, you'll need to tell us about the shape of the baseband signal. Is it a digital pulse train? 2. The circuit you show is not a modulator.  A transformer is linear, so it does not mix frequencies. 3. 100mA through a human body is freakishly dangerous.

Comment: Any solution which isn't based on the MCU giving a PWM with it's own preferred logic levels (3V3 etc) is probably flawed. Use analog electronics based on such a signal to get whatever it is you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit in your YouTube link is a very poor attempt to make an AM modulator - which you can probably guess by the very poor results! Best to ignore it.

Your 'rough idea' about a circuit is OK - except for an obvious error in the modulation part.

> Can I avoid some or all of the analog circuit shown above?

You could avoid some of it but the output quality will be worse, which may need *more* parts to fix (and you need more parts anyway to make a properly working circuit).

> Is there any diffrence in the final modulated signal if created using
> pulse width modulation technique instead of amplitude modulation
> technique? PWM is provided in hardware in the microcontroller.

Yes. If you create the modulating signal using PWM it will have harmonics which need to be filtered out. If you do this *before* feeding the signal into the transformer then you won't have to worry about possible intermodulation products (which may be impossible to filter out later).

Now to address the main problem with your circuit...

Your modulating MOSFET is connected directly from Vdd to GND, which will do nothing except short out the power supply. It needs to be connected between Vdd and the transformer center tap, and it needs to be a P-Channel type. Better yet would be to use two FETs (which could both be NMOS) in a half-bridge (push-pull) configuration.

Feed the output of that into a low pass filter to remove the PWM harmonics and 'reconstruct' the analog waveform. In effect this a Digital to Analog Converter (DAC), producing an output voltage which is used to modulate the amplitude of the carrier wave by varying the supply voltage to the transformer.

The transformer output will be a square wave at the carrier frequency, whose amplitude is determined by the 'DAC' voltage. This square wave will have strong harmonics possibly reaching out to several MHz. If you want a 'pure' final output then you will need to feed it through a band pass filter centered at 10 kHz.

Comment: I have edited the modulated signal circuit, as per your guidlines. Can you please confirm and suggest further. thank you.

Comment: Getting there. Use a 'half-bridge' Gate driver to drive Q1 and Q2, and put a _passive_ LC filter on the output.

Comment: Added Half Bridge MOSFET Gate Driver circuit and Passive LC Circuit as well. Another requirement, where i have to vary the amplitude of the Messege Signal from 0 - VCC , without changing the shape of the signal to get the AM index from 0-100%. Now my confusion is , to get the shape of sine wave i have to do the PWM. Do PWM also change the amplitude of the signal.

Comment: A PWM sine wave can go from 0 to 100% of Vcc, but your half bridge driver cannot do 100% _continuously_ unless you use a separate boost supply. It might be better to limit the range to eg. 1% to 99% to ensure that the boost capacitor stays charged.

Comment: 1% to 99% would do fine. In software i think i have to limit the timing of pulse duration to get the Modulation Index. am i correct?

Comment: What about changig the Duty Cycle of Carrier to get the required Modulation Index ?

Comment: That is another option. You would a need a good passive filter on the output remove the the large amount of harmonics produced.

Comment: Yes you are right , the more no. of step pwm would be, the more harmonics it would produce at output. Can you provide any link , how to design the LC Filter for above circuit please.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what @KevinWhite said, 10 kHz ± 150 Hz is well within the range of any ordinary audio DAC, and pretty much any modern MCU would be able to do the math to drive it. In other words, you can synthesize the complete modulated signal in software, which is called [software-defined radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio) (SDR).

After that, all you need to do is amplify the signal to whatever power level you desire, which can be handled by any audio amplifier with the necessary ratings.

Comment: I said 1MHz was too fast to process with a small MCU. The original schematic has 300-1200kHz.